# One Select instead of UnionAll

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, view

This is my Tables:

```
[Member]: 
{ [Id], [UserId], [UserName], [Email], [Status_Id], [MemberType_Id] }

[CustomerProfile] :
{ [Id], [Member_Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [SSN], [Gender], [PostalCode],[City_Id], [Address]}


[DealerProfile]:
{ [Id], [Member_Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [SSN], [Gender], [StoreName], [PostalCode], [City_Id], [Address] }


[ManagerProfile]
{ [Id], [Member_Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [SSN], [Gender] }

[City]:
{ [Id], [Title], [Province_Id] }
```

So I need to create a full view of all my members and related columns.

I must mention that [Member].[Id] is just in one of 3 profile tables. its mean that one Member can have one type Customer, dealer or manager

At first I am going to start with the following select query:

```
 SELECT     
[ME].[Id] AS [MemberId],
[ME].[UserId],
[ME].[UserName],
[ME].[Status_Id],
[ST].[Title] AS [Status],
[ME].[MemberType_Id],
[MT].[Title] AS [MemberType],

CASE
    WHEN [MT].[Title]='Customer' THEN [CUP].[FirstName]
    WHEN [MT].[Title]='Dealer' THEN [DEP].[FirstName]
    WHEN [MT].[Title]='Manager' THEN [MAP].[FirstName]
    ELSE 'Unknown' END AS [FirstName],
CASE
    WHEN [MT].[Title]='Customer' THEN [CUP].[LastName]
    WHEN [MT].[Title]='Dealer' THEN [DEP].[LastName]
    WHEN [MT].[Title]='Manager' THEN [MAP].[LastName]
    ELSE 'Unknown' END AS [LastName]

FROM [Members].[Member] AS [ME]
INNER JOIN [Members].[MemberType] AS [MT] ON [ME].[MemberType_Id] = [MT].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Members].[Status] AS [ST] ON [ME].[Status_Id]=[ST].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Members].[ManagerProfile] AS [MAP] ON [ME].[Id]= [MAP].[Member_Id]
INNER JOIN [Members].[CustomerProfile] AS [CUP] ON [ME].[Id]=[CUP].[Member_Id]
INNER JOIN [Members].[DealerProfile] AS [DEP] ON [ME].[Id]=[DEP].[Member_Id];
```

But as I said before The [Member].[ID] is just in one of 3 profile tables so the above query returned null and I think use `Union All` like this:

```
(SELECT   
[ME].[Id] AS [MemberId],
[ME].[UserId],
[ME].[UserName],
[ME].[Status_Id],
[ST].[Title] AS [Status],
[ME].[MemberType_Id],
[MT].[Title] AS [MemberType],
[PR].[FirstName] AS [FirstName],
[PR].[LastName] AS [LastName]

FROM [Members].[Member] AS [ME]
INNER JOIN [Members].[MemberType] AS [MT] ON [ME].[MemberType_Id] = [MT].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Members].[Status] AS [ST] ON [ME].[Status_Id]=[ST].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Members].[CustomerProfile] AS [PR] ON [ME].[Id]=[PR].[Member_Id])
UNION ALL
(SELECT   
[ME].[Id] AS [MemberId],
[ME].[UserId],
[ME].[UserName],
[ME].[Status_Id],
[ST].[Title] AS [Status],
[ME].[MemberType_Id],
[MT].[Title] AS [MemberType],
[PR].[FirstName] AS [FirstName],
[PR].[LastName] AS [LastName]

FROM [Members].[Member] AS [ME]
INNER JOIN [Members].[MemberType] AS [MT] ON [ME].[MemberType_Id] = [MT].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Members].[Status] AS [ST] ON [ME].[Status_Id]=[ST].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Members].[DealerProfile] AS [PR] ON [ME].[Id]=[PR].[Member_Id])
UNION ALL
(SELECT   
[ME].[Id] AS [MemberId],
[ME].[UserId],
[ME].[UserName],
[ME].[Status_Id],
[ST].[Title] AS [Status],
[ME].[MemberType_Id],
[MT].[Title] AS [MemberType],
[PR].[FirstName] AS [FirstName],
[PR].[LastName] AS [LastName]

FROM [Members].[Member] AS [ME]
INNER JOIN [Members].[MemberType] AS [MT] ON [ME].[MemberType_Id] = [MT].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Members].[Status] AS [ST] ON [ME].[Status_Id]=[ST].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Members].[ManagerProfile] AS [PR] ON [ME].[Id]=[PR].[Member_Id])
```

So what do you think, is this good way to create a view such as my view's? is there any better way to create view with better performance instead use of `Union All`? what is your suggestion about shortest way and best performance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10119260/1175585

Answer (score 1):

UNION ALL often yields rather poor performance.

An alternative would be to have an inner query that uses LEFT OUTER JOIN, and an outer query that uses CASE statements to select the relevant fields.  I suspect that will yield much better performance for you.

To keep things simple, let's use just your customer profile and dealer profile table.  The same concept would apply as you extend it to other tables in the join.  Another approach, using left outer joins, would look something like this:

```
create view MembersView as
select Id, 
case
    when not FirstName_cp is null then FirstName_cp
    when not FirstName_dp is null then First_name_dp
    else null
end as FirstName,
case
    when not LastName_cp is null then LastName_cp
    when not LastName_dp is null then Last_name_dp
    else null
end as LastName
from 
(

    select m.[Id] as Member_Id, cp.[FirstName] as FirstName_cp, 
           cp.[LastName] as LastName_cp, 
           dp.[FirstName] as FirstName_dp, 
           dp.[LastName] as LastName_dp
    from [Member] m
    left outer join [CustomerProfile] cp on
        m.Id = cp.Member_Id
    left outer join DealProfile dp on
        m.Id = dp.Member_Id
) as TBL
```

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN`s with `COALESCE`

```
SELECT     
[ME].[Id] AS [MemberId],
[ME].[UserId],
[ME].[UserName],
[ME].[Status_Id],
[ST].[Title] AS [Status],
[ME].[MemberType_Id],
[MT].[Title] AS [MemberType],
[FirstName]=COALESCE([CUP].[FirstName],[DEP].[FirstName],[MAP].[FirstName],'Unknown'),
[LastName]=COALESCE([CUP].[LastName],[DEP].[LastName],[MAP].[LastName],'Unknown')
FROM [Members].[Member] AS [ME]
INNER JOIN [Members].[MemberType] AS [MT] ON [ME].[MemberType_Id] = [MT].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Members].[Status] AS [ST] ON [ME].[Status_Id]=[ST].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Members].[ManagerProfile] AS [MAP] ON [ME].[Id]= [MAP].[Member_Id]
LEFT JOIN [Members].[CustomerProfile] AS [CUP] ON [ME].[Id]=[CUP].[Member_Id]
LEFT JOIN [Members].[DealerProfile] AS [DEP] ON [ME].[Id]=[DEP].[Member_Id];
```